# What is the average daily cost for defective components?

Tags: probability, expected-value

A typical day’s production of a certain electronic component is twelve. The probability that one of these components needs rework is $0.11$. Each component needing rework costs $\$100$. What is the average daily cost for defective components?

I understand that we can make Y how many components needed reworking, therefore: Y = [0, 1, 2, ... 12]

Also that the average daily cost for the defective components would equal 100 * Expected Value(Y) But how would I go about finding the probabilities of more than 1 component needing a rework.

Answer (score 1):

We're only looking for expected value. The expected number of components that need rework, given that $12$ are produced in a day on average, is $12×0.11=1.32$. Then multiply this by $100$ to get $132$ dollars as the expected cost per day.